# Do I need to use "document.getElementById"

Tags: javascript

I still haven't the got this code to work correctly in ie9. It works ok in Firefox though. Do I have to use "document.getElementById" for it to work in ie9? If so, where would it fit in?

```
function dbasetype(){

var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");

var _area = document.forms[0]._area;        
var _dbase_name = document.forms[0]._dbase_name;

if  (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")==-1) {
        _area.value = _dbase_name.value;            
     }  else { setarea(); } 
     }
```

**EDIT**
The above code updates a field (that controls the access for individuals) in a database when the save button is clicked. It works ok in Firefox as I said previously but when this runs in ie9 the field that is supposed to be updated and is replaced with a blank and then the user loses access to the contact record.

Comment: This is definitely your problem: `var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value`;

Comment: What kind of question is this? "I paste my code on SO and others need to fix it"? Provide some information what you're trying to accomplish and what's not working well.

Comment: Sorry, very new to this and didn't know about acceptance ticks. Have now accepted some answers.

Comment: why don't you use jquery, when it is there? It'll be easy to use

Comment: @NishuTayal: Where is it? I can't see it in the question.

Comment: @Bergi : I mean, when jquery is available,instead of javascript, that can be used. I know, its not in the question.

Comment: @NishuTayal: jQuery cannot be used if javascript is not available, you should know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the IE has the stupid property that every ID is also a global (readonly) object. You just have to rename your variable in your JavaScript like this:

```
function dbasetype() {
  var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
  dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, "");

  var x_area = document.forms[0]._area;        
  var x_dbase_name = document.forms[0]._dbase_name;

  if(dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")==-1) {
    x_area.value = x_dbase_name.value;            
  } else {
    setarea();
  } 
}
```

Comment: rekire, you are a life saver. much appreciated. It's very difficult when starting out on this stuff. I have now moved a bit further towards the light. thx

Comment: Some month ago I had the same wired behavior.